# Call a function from different file where the file name and function name are read from a list

Tags: python, arrays, function

I have multiple functions stored in different files, Both file names and function names are stored in lists. Is there any option to call the required function without the conditional statements?
Example, `file1` has functions `function11` and `function12`,

```
def function11():
    pass
def function12():
    pass
```

`file2` has functions `function21` and `function22`

```
def function21():
    pass
def function22():
    pass
```

and I have the lists

```
file_name = ["file1", "file2", "file1"]
function_name = ["function12", "function22", "funciton12"]
```

I will get the list index from different function, based on that I need to call the function and get the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the other function will give you a list index directly, then you don't need to deal with the function names as strings. Instead, directly store (without calling) the functions in the list:

```
import file1, file2

functions = [file1.function12, file2.function22, file1.function12]
```

And then call them once you have the index:

```
function[index]()
```

There *are* ways to do what is called "reflection" in Python and get from the string to a matching-named function. But they solve a problem that is more advanced than what you describe, and they are more difficult (especially if you also have to work with the module names).

---

If you have a "whitelist" of functions and modules that are allowed to be called from the config file, but still need to find them by string, you can explicitly create the mapping with a dict:

```
allowed_functions = {
    'file1': {
        'function11': file1.function11,
        'function12': file1.function12
    },
    'file2': {
        'function21': file2.function21,
        'function22': file2.function22
    }
}
```

And then invoke the function:

```
try:
    func = allowed_functions[module_name][function_name]
except KeyError:
    raise ValueError("this function/module name is not allowed")
else:
    func()
```

---

The most advanced approach is if you need to load code from a "plugin" module created by the author. You can use the standard library `importlib` package to use the string name to find a file to import as a module, and import it dynamically. It looks something like:

```
from importlib.util import spec_from_file_location, module_from_spec

# Look for the file at the specified path, figure out the module name
# from the base file name, import it and make a module object.
def load_module(path):
    folder, filename = os.path.split(path)
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    spec = spec_from_file_location(basename, path)
    module = module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    assert module.__name__ == basename
    return module
```

This is **still unsafe**, in the sense that it can look anywhere on the file system for the module. Better if you specify the folder yourself, and only allow a filename to be used in the config file; but then you *still* have to protect against hacking the path by using things like ".." and "/" in the "filename".

(I have a project that does something like this. It chooses the paths from a whitelist that is also under the user's control, so I have to warn my users not to trust the path-whitelist file from each other. I also search the directories for modules, and then make a whitelist of plugins that may be used, based only on plugins that are in the directory - so no funny games with "..". And I'm *still* worried I forgot something.)

Once you have a module name, you can get a function from it by name like:

```
dynamic_module = load_module(some_path)
try:
    func = getattr(dynamic_module, function_name)
except AttributeError:
    raise ValueError("function not in module")
```

At any rate, there is no reason to `eval` anything, or generate and import code based on user input. That is most unsafe of all.

Comment: I will get the list from the configuration file, I can't store like this!

Comment: Oh, this should be mentioned in the question, then. But also: who will create the configuration file? There is a potential for security risk if the file names functions that you don't want to be called (maybe not even from your own code, but e.g. the standard library, if I put `"sys.exit"` in the config file in whatever format).

Comment: I will generate the configuration file, but I cant change the configuration file other functions are dependent on it

Comment: I added some more ways to do it. Please be careful and only allow as much power to the user as you really need to.

Comment: I actually totally agree with not using `eval`. My second post using `__init__.py` is slightly better - but not much :D

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you post is also one of the solution for my question, But I wanted a single line which solves my issue.

Comment: You won't get this in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I'm understanding the need. Maybe more detail in the question.

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
m = ["os"]
f = ["getcwd"]
command = ''.join([m[0], ".", f[0], "()"])
# Put in some minimum sanity checking and sanitization!!!
if ";" in command or <other dangerous string> in command:
        print("The line '{}' is suspicious. Will not run".format(command))
        sys.exit(1)
print("This will error if the method isnt imported...")
print(eval(''.join([m[0], ".", f[0], "()"])) )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
This will error if the method isnt imported...
/home/rightmire/eclipse-workspace/junkcode
```

As pointed out by @KarlKnechtel, having commands come in from an external file is a gargantuan security risk!

Comment: How to pass parameters to using this?

Comment: You mentioned you were getting the import names from two lists. `file_name = ["file1", "file2", "file1"]` and `function_name = ["function12", "function22", "funciton12"]`. Thats also what I have above, except I called `file_name` "m" (for module, which is the correct term for the file name.) And I called `function_name` " f " (for function) :)

Comment: I would still seriously recommend adding some sanity checking and input sanitization before running any command that is derived from external input (see my other answer as well.)

Comment: I am not getting the import names from external file, I will get only the function name and in which file it is located.

Comment: OK. I understand your problem. So, the best way to solve this is to ensure your filenames, classes, and methods are consistently named. If you want to grab a function (method) out of a file, you need to import it. I'll change the code above to explain better.

Comment: Thank You, no need to change anything, I got the answer for my comment.

Comment: OK Honestly, based on you description - my **other** answer is far better than this one. You really should be importing them, and doing it  via the `__init__.py` file. Because `__init__.py`  has such a well-defined format for the import (I.e. from `<filename-without-the-.py> import <function_name>`) it's very easy to sanitize.

Comment: Your second method helps only in importing the required filenames, what I was actually looking was this post to know how to call the function using the names stored in list.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative. This is ***not*** much safer than an `eval()` however.

Someone with access to the lists you read from the config file could inject malicious code in the lists you import.

I.e.

```
'from subprocess import call; subprocess.call(["rm", "-rf", "./*" stdout=/dev/null, stderr=/dev/null, shell=True)'
```

**Code:**

```
import re
# You must first create a directory named "test_module"
# You can do this with code if needed. 
# Python recognizes a "module" as a module by the existence of an __init__.py
# It will load that __init__.py at the "import" command, and you can access the methods it imports
m = ["os", "sys", "subprocess"] # Modules to import from
f = ["getcwd", "exit", "call; call('do', '---terrible-things')"] # Methods to import

# Create an __init__.py
with open("./test_module/__init__.py", "w") as FH:
    for count in range(0, len(m), 1):
        # Writes "from module import method" to __init.py 
        line = "from {} import {}\n".format(m[count], f[count])
        # !!!! SANITIZE THE LINE !!!!!
        if not re.match("^from [a-zA-Z0-9._]+ import [a-zA-Z0-9._]+$", line):
            print("The line '{}' is suspicious. Will not be entered into __init__.py!!".format(line))
            continue
        FH.write(line)

import test_module
print(test_module.getcwd())
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
The line 'from subprocess import call; call('do', '---terrible-things')' is suspicious. Will not be entered into __init__.py!!
/home/rightmire/eclipse-workspace/junkcode
```